# Selectively merging file contents

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to match two files and print only those lines that after specific character are not followed only by elements from one of the file.

eg I have two files that look like this:

```
 1A00.pdb_HEM_COA
 1A01.pdb_HEM
 1A05.pdb_IPM
 1A0F.pdb_GTS_4CA
 1A0G.pdb_PMP
 1A0I.pdb_2CP
```

and this:

```
COA
2CP
3CP
3HC
4CA
4CO
```

I want to match them and if it appears that first `_` is only followed by elements from second file then don't print them (example is `1A0I.pdb_2CP`). If in other lines it appears that `_` is followed some other element but also by element from second file as well then just delete this element that is common in both files but print the line (example is `1A00.pdb_HEM_COA` and printed line should be like `1A00.pdb_HEM`).

Does anybody has any idea how to do that?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the examples? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried something in `perl` but had a hard time matching the lines in which only elements from the second list appear after `_`.

Comment: When a non-matching string is present, is it always the first one after the hyphen? if so, you can just trim hyphen-delimited fields from the end until they stop matching

Comment: @steeldriver It doesn't have to be first it can appear in first, second and every other place. So, just whenever it matches delete the string and whenevet it matches "alone" after hyphen then delete whole line..

Comment: I was thinking to give it a try in perl tomorrow..

Comment: Pity - for your sample data (where that *does* seem to be the case) you could do `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="_"} NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} {while ($NF in a) NF--} NF>1 {print}' file2 file1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `perl` hash from the lines of the second file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

BEGIN{ $/ = $\ = "\n"; }

my $stringsfile = shift @ARGV;
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $stringsfile)
  or die "Could not open file '$stringsfile' $!";

my %h;

while (defined($_ = <$fh>)) {
    chomp $_;
    $h{$_} = 1;
}
```

and then split lines of the first (and subsequent) files into hyphen-separated fields, grep for those fields that are not in the hash, and join it all back together and print if the grep returns anything:

```
while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) { 
    chomp $_;
    my ($x, @F) = split(/_/, $_, 0);
    my @y = grep({not $h{$_};} @F);
    print join('_', $x, @y) if @y;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./foo.pl file2 file1
 1A00.pdb_HEM
 1A01.pdb_HEM
 1A05.pdb_IPM
 1A0F.pdb_GTS
 1A0G.pdb_PMP
```

---

Note: if the potential matches are all at the end, then there's a much simpler approach using `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS="_"} 
  NR==FNR {a[$0]++; next} 
  {while ($NF in a) NF--} 
  NF>1 {print}
' file2 file1
```

For the sample data in your question, both approaches produce the same output.

Comment: Potential matches dont have to be at the end of each line. This perl script worked fine. Thank You!

Comment: I have just checked it once again and script fails to delete those lines whenever after hyphen only element from second list appears. When I use these examples from the question it works proprely but when I include `100` more `elements` into `file2`, it fails to process. Does the `size` of a file can be a problem? My `file2` has around `160 elements` and `file1` has around `100 lines`..

Comment: AFAIK there is no line limit - it works for me on the last line of your test file - my guess is that some of your lines have trailing whitespace characters.

Comment: Yeah it also works perfectly for me on these data from the question but having problems with bigger data..it is surely not anything about the script but about input files. Thank You for this clever suggestion I will delete all whitespace for the input and then try!